# c# linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml string that I wish to traverse using LINQ to XML (I have never used this, so wish to learn).  However when I try to use

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(adminUsersXML);
        var users = from result in xDoc.Descendants("Result")
                    select new
                    {
                        test = result.Element("USER_ID").Value
                    };
```

I get an error message saying illegal characters in path.  reading up on it, it's because I cannot pass a standard string in this way.  Is there a way to use XML LINQ qith a standard string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that `adminUsersXML` is the XML itself rather than a path to a *file* containing XML. If that's the case, just use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(adminUsersXML);
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx), you must use the `Parse` function to create a XDocument from a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think `adminUserXML` is not a file but a string containing xml, which should be parsed to convert to XDocument with `XDocument.Parse(adminUserXML)`